# KeyNotFoundException with online database

Tags: c#, database, exception

I'm trying to connect to a free online database (db4free.net) and I can't because KeyNotFoundException is thrown when the program tries to open connection.

Here's my code:

```
public static class BaseDeDatos { 
    static string myConnectionString = "SERVER=db4free.net;" + "DATABASE=******;" + "UID=******;" + "PASSWORD=*****;"; 
    static MySqlConnection cnx = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);

            static String error;

            public static int Conectar()
            {
                int resultado = -1;
                try
                {
                    cnx.Open(); //The exception is thrown HERE
                    if (cnx.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                        resultado = 1;
                }
                catch (MySqlException ex)
                {
                    error = ex.Message;
                }
                return resultado;
            }

          .
          .
          .
          .
          public static void myMethod(){

                 Conectar();

         }
        }
```

When I call `myMethod()` the exception is thrown. I can connect this database with MySQLWorkbench, and to PHP Android, but why I can't do this connection in Visual Studio with C#? I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong Help me, please

PD: I was reading that I need to change the character set of my database, but It doesn't work. I tried with all the character set availables

Comment: What is the exact error message? Did you install [Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)?

Comment: Yes, the error come from the connection String, because I use this connection string to other database and It works for me, but I think that db4free have a differente connection string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at other examples such as [Connecting to a Online MySQL Database using VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269237/connecting-to-a-online-mysql-database-using-vb-net)

```
MySQLConnection.ConnectionString = "server=db4free.net;Port=3306; User ID=db4freeusername; password=db4freepassword; database=nameofyourdatabase"
```

They are specifying a port number, could this be your problem?

Comment: No, this isn't the solution. I tried a lot of combinations to create connection string, and I haven't idea which I need to use

Comment: OK, try using my connection string          static string myConnectionString = "SERVER=db4free.net;DATABASE=omega900;UID=chris_csjt;PASSWORD=P@ssword;";
and see if that works from your code.  It does work from here

Comment: The first solution is the correct friend. I don't know what was the problem, but I create a new database, and it works. I guess that settings was wrong in database. Thanks you.